# Magento 2.3.0 Account Sidebar without success

Tags: magento2, account

I have tried to add a Custom link to my Magento Account page side-bar. but cannot add even I cannot remove as well.
I added

> Magento_Customer/layout/customer_account.xml

and copied the `customer_account.xml` from `module_customer` and paste

but nothing is happening.

Comment: update your xml file which you have changed

Comment: @Rakesh Varma. Sir, can you please help??

Comment: update your xml file in question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use below content for you customer_account.xml to add new link there in My Account sidebar section

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="2columns-left" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd" label="Customer My Account (All Pages)" design_abstraction="custom">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="customer_account_navigation">
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Link\Current" name="custom-link-left-sidebar">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Custom Link Left Sidebar</argument>
                    <argument name="path" xsi:type="string">custom/index/index</argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

In above content you can use your Block class name instead of using **Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Link\Current** this

You can remove any link using below line in your xml file

```
<referenceBlock name="your-block-name" remove="true" />
```

You can add your block name where I have mentioned **'your-block-name'**. For e.g. If you want to remove wishlist link then you can find block name of wishlist link here in this file..

> vendor/magento/module-wishlist/view/frontend/layout/customer_account.xml

there is one block with this name "customer-account-navigation-wish-list-link" that is your wishlist link block you can use this name in referenceBlock name and just add remove="true" after it.

After adding this you can clear and flush cache using commands

```
php bin/magento cache:clean
php bin/magento cache:flush
```

Hope this may help you!

Comment: Thanks a lot, Sir. It worked for me. 
May I ask you how to remove a link?

Comment: Which link you want to remove ?

Comment: I've updated my answer, you can check that. If it will work for you then you can accept my answer and upvote ;)

Comment: wish list. and is it possible to add a phtml file??

Comment: I've updated answer for wishlist. please check that and where you want to add phtml file ?

Comment: is this helpful to you ?

Comment: Yes, Sir. I clicked on helpful but For being a new user I can not vote.

Comment: You can approve my answer then:)

Comment: I did it, Sir. otherwise you can tell me the way to do that.

Comment: Thanks Buddy. :) Happy to help you. :)

Answer (score 2):

Add xml file in your theme layout `customer_account.xml` and add that code in xml file

```
<referenceBlock name="customer_account_navigation">
    <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Link\Current" name="customer-account-navigation-custom-link" after="-" >
         <arguments>
             <argument name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Custom Label</argument>
             <argument name="path" xsi:type="string">my-path-url</argument>
         </arguments>
    </block>
</referenceBlock>
```